# How to run all stages in parallel in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to execute all the stages in parallel with the loop based on user input.
This gives error because `script` is not allowed under `stages`.
How should I achieve the same?

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'ec2'
        }
    }
    stages{
        script{
            int[] array = params.elements; 
            for(int i in array) { 
                parallel{
                    stage('Preparation') { 
                        echo 'Preparation'
                        println(i); 
                    }
                    stage('Build') {
                        echo 'Build'
                        println(i); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using declarative pipelines you have two options, first is to use [static parallel stages](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel) which is an integral part of the declarative syntax but does not allow dynamic or runtime modifications.
The second option (which is probably what you attempted) is to use the scripted [parallel](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#parallel-execute-in-parallel) function:

> ````
> parallel firstBranch: {
>     // do something
> }, secondBranch: {
>     // do something else
> },
> failFast: true|false```
> ````

When using it inside a declarative pipeline it should be used inside a `script` block like you did but the declarative basic directive must still be kept: `pipeline` -> `stages` -> `stage` -> `steps` -> `script`. In addition the scripted parallel function receives a specifically formatted map alike the example above.
In your case it can look somethong like:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'ec2'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Parallel Execution') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel params.elements.collectEntries {
                        // the key of each entry is the parallel execution branch name
                        // and the value of each entry is the code to execute
                        ["Iteration for ${it}" : {
                            stage('Preparation') {
                                echo 'Preparation'
                                println(it);
                            }
                            stage('Build') {
                                echo 'Build'
                                println(it);
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you want to use the for loop:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'ec2'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Parallel Execution') {
            steps {
                script {
                    map executions = [:]
                    for(int i in params.elements) {
                        executions["Iteration for ${it}" ] = {
                            stage('Preparation') {
                                echo 'Preparation'
                                println(i);
                            }
                            stage('Build') {
                                echo 'Build'
                                println(i);
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                    parallel executions
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Other useful examples for the `parallel` function can be found [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#parallel-from-list)